# Excel Pivot table how to get average of a min field

Tags: excel, pivot, pivot-table, powerpivot

I am trying to calculate average of a min field using pivot tables. I can do it in 2 steps right now but was wondering if its possible to do in 1 step using the pivot table. Right now I have to do a min pivot table and then copy paste that into another table and do another pivot on it.
[image]

edit: I have uploaded sample here: https://easyupload.io/b6wvfd

[image]

Comment: First, don't you need each region value in the first column populated??

Comment: Sorry yes, all of the A is US and b or c is AU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using DAX you could achieve it by using two measures:

First calculate the Minimum of the items, `Min of item`:

```
=MINX(Table1,Table1[age])
```

Then do average of the minimum values, `Avg of Min`:

```
=AVERAGEX(ALL(Table1[item]),
[Min of item])
```

Result should be like this:
[image]

---

**Setup the PowerPivot Table**

Transform your data into a table.

We can now create the PowerPivot and add the data to the data model
[image]

Then create a new measure by clicking your pivot table and then "Measures" -> "New Measure..."

[image]

Fill in all the relevant data and start with creating the "Min of item" variable.

[image]

Then create the average of min (since we use the previous measure in this function):

[image]

Comment: no luck with this, error that to few arguments passed. https://ibb.co/vjP6ypn

Comment: The one you write won't work since you don't specify the table. You need to copy and create first the MINX() as mentioned. Then you need to create the AVERAGEX(). So you need _both_ formulas to make this work :). Here's a copy of the [excel file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/q3iefu41o7t7zs4/book2%20-%20average%20of%20min%20value%20stack_3.xlsx?dl=0)

Answer (score 0):

i got it to work using power query.:

1. Transform your table as table
2. load power query
3. do a group by region and sub and use min function
4. On that add a step to group by region and do the average